# How do I configure travis so that a specific gemfile uses a specific version of ruby only?

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

So how do I configure this travis ci file so that the rails5 gemfile only tests/uses ruby 2.2.2?  Activesupport 5 requires ruby 2.2.2.

```
language: ruby
env:
  - CI=true
before_script:
  - "bundle exec rake db:prepare"
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
  - 2.1.6
  - 2.2.2
gemfile:
  - gemfiles/rails32.gemfile
  - gemfiles/rails4.gemfile
  - gemfiles/rails41.gemfile
  - gemfiles/rails42.gemfile
  - gemfiles/rails5beta.gemfile
notifications:
  recipients:
    - someone@gmail.com
    - someone2@gmail.com
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it will work, but bundler supports the `ruby` keyword, so you can do something like `ruby "2.2.2"` at the top of your gemfiles.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a build `matrix` like this:

```
language: ruby
env:
  - CI=true
before_script:
  - "bundle exec rake db:prepare"
matrix:
  include:
    - rvm: 2.0.0
      gemfile:
        - gemfiles/rails32.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails4.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails41.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails42.gemfile
    - rvm: 2.1.6
      gemfile:
        - gemfiles/rails32.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails4.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails41.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails42.gemfile
    - rvm: 2.2.2
      gemfile:
        - gemfiles/rails32.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails4.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails41.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails42.gemfile
        - gemfiles/rails5beta.gemfile
notifications:
  recipients:
    - someone@gmail.com
    - someone2@gmail.com
```

See docs at: [Travis CI - Customizing the Build - Build Matrix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - apparently, Travis includes a matrix option to allow you to not run certain Ruby versions with a particular gemfile (or to run them)

```
matrix:
    exclude:
    - rvm: 2.0.0
        gemfile: Gemfile
        env: DB=mongodb
    - rvm: 2.0.0
        gemfile: Gemfile
        env: DB=redis
    - rvm: 2.0.0
        gemfile: Gemfile
        env: DB=mysql
```